# Показ части текста до нужного тэга

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Ребята, помогите с регулярными выражениями. Есть текст большой-большой, мне надо только часть показать, например, до тега `<!--more-->`, например

> Это текст, который нужно показывать`<!--more-->`, а этот не нужно.

А то сайт делаю, и не могу придумать так, чтобы статья не показывалась полностью.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
$message = "Ребята, помогите с регулярными выражениями. Есть текст большой-большой, мне надо только часть показать, например, до тега <!--more-->, например";
$message = preg_replace("/(.*)(<!--more-->.*)/i", "$1", $message);
echo $message;
```

Будет выведено
**Ребята, помогите с регулярными выражениями. Есть текст большой-большой, мне надо только часть показать, например, до тега**

Answer (score 3):

```
$ar = explode('<!--more-->', $text);
echo $ar[0];
```

Вариант А

```
$ar = explode(' ', $text);
echo implode(' ', array_slice($ar, 0, 20);),'...'; // первые 20 слов, тег разбивки не нужен
```

Вариант Б

Answer (score 1):

хранить в таблице краткую новость (обрезать до заданной длины, например 255 символов) и полную новость

Comment: я не использую Mysql